# Hide login/register button when logged in and hide logout button when logged out

Tags: php, html

i'm kinda new in PHP and I have some issues. When I'm logged in on my website I want to hide the 'Login' and 'Register' button, and when I'm logged out I want to hide the 'logout' button.

This is my login.php page:

```
<?php
    include "navbar.php";
?>
<?php
    include_once "check.php";

    $error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            $error = "Both fields are required.";
        }else
        {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            // To protect from MySQL injection
            $username = stripslashes($username);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
            $password = md5($password);

            //Check username and password from database
            $sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            //If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
            //Otherwise echo error.

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("location: index.php");
            }else
            {
                $error = "Incorrect username or password.";
            }

        }
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/acc.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/acc2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/navbar.css">
        <title>Login | Peerbolte-ICT</title>
    </head>
    </body>
        <section>
        <p style="color:red;"><?php echo $error; ?> </p>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <div class="accPanel">
                <h1 style="color: black; padding-bottom: 5%;">Login</h1>
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    <div class="login-input">
                        <label class="accLabel"><b>Username<span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

                        <label class="accLabel"><b>Password<span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

                        <button class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my navbar.php where the buttons are:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#bannerTwo">Services</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Our Work</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Account</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="login.php">Login</a>
      <a href="register.php">Register</a>
      <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: check my answer that will help you

Comment: You should not be using MD5 for passwords any more.  It's obsolete! https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can display your link based on condition. check session for that if user login you get **session** value on base of that logic you can put condition like below:

```
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) )
{
?>
      <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
     <a href="login.php">Login</a>
     <a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php } ?>
```

**Note:** make your you start session in file.

Comment: This is almost working, it only shows me the Login/Register button. But when i'm logged in, it still shows me that 2 buttons and not the logout button.

Comment: @DamiënPeerbolte session_start(); in your file?

Comment: @DamiënPeerbolte did u start the session?

Comment: Fotgot that, but it's working now. Thank you guys soo much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sessions to check if a user is logged in or logged out.

```
$_SESSION['status'] = 1;//if logged in
$_SESSION['status'] = 0;//if logged out
```

To hide the links, you can use this:

```
<a href="login.php" <?php echo ($_SESSION['status'] == 1) ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ?> >Login</a>
<a href="register.php" <?php echo ($_SESSION['status'] == 1) ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ?>>Register</a>
<a href="logout.php" <?php echo ($_SESSION['status'] == 0) ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ?>>Logout</a>
```

And don't forget to the put `session_start()` so that you can use sessions

Comment: It shows me the same 2 buttons (login and register) when i'm logged in

Comment: Just saw my mistake, but it is impossible that both login and register are visible because they have different condition

Comment: Did you start the session? And do you change the value of `$_SESSION['status']` whenever you are logging in or logging out?

Comment: Did you just copy and pasted the answer in your codes? Or did you apply the proper logic for the `$_SESSION['status']`?

Comment: I messed around with the conditions a bit, but i got my answer. So thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Put a check using `session` on the top of login/logout button like:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) )
{
    // User is logged in, show logout menu here
}
else
{
    // User is not logged in, show login menu here
}
```

**Explanation:** `$_SESSION['username']` is set only when the user login is successful after checking the login credentials and removed on logout.

Comment: So the buttons in the navbar.php will be like this?

  `<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Account</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
  <?php
   if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) )
   {
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
   }
   else
   {
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
   }
  ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && empty($error): ?>

        here you display your logout button

   <?php else: ?>

        display login button

   <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this code use alternative syntax, better to add html in the middle

Comment: what is 'not working" ? got some errors or something ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#bannerTwo">Services</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Our Work</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Account</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">

    <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    echo "<a href=\"login.php\">Login</a>
          <a href=\"register.php\">Register</a>"; ?> 

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>"; ?>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now it shows me only the register and logout button when i'm logged out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest technique I'm using for my blog. I hope this will work for everyone...

**Below code:** If the user is logged in, the login menu will not display

```
<li><?php  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a><?php endif ?></li>
```

**Below code:** If the user is logged in, the logout will be display

```
<li><?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
<a href="homepage.php?logout='1'">LOGOUT</a>
<?php endif ?></li>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to use session_start()